# Guid & GetHashCode uniqueness

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following key:

```
int key = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
```

Is this key unique as the uniqueness of Guid?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) says no. A GUID has 16 bytes of information* - 128 bits. An `int` has only 32 bits of information.

There are 2<sup>128</sup> possible GUIDs, and 2<sup>32</sup> possible hash codes - so you can't *possibly* have a different hash code for each GUID.

There's more than that though - `GetHashCode()` is never *meant* to represent uniqueness. If it *can*, then that's great - but it doesn't have to, even when there are enough `int` values available to do so.

It would be entirely *valid* for `int.GetHashCode()` to return (say) the value divided by two... so -1, 0 and 1 would all get a hash code of 0; 3 and 4 would get a hash code of 2 etc. It wouldn't be good (and it would be slower than just returning the value) - but it would be a valid implementation. It would satisfy all the constraints of `GetHashCode` - namely that if you call it on two equal values, it will return the same hash code.

In fact, returning a constant for *all* values is a valid implementation - although a pretty useless one, in that it renders the normally-fast lookup of a hash table into an O(N) operation.

---

* - To clarify due to comments, the .NET GUID will allow these 128 bits to be set arbitrarily as far as I'm aware; randomly generated GUIDs follow a stricter pattern so there aren't 2<sup>128</sup> different values which would be randomly generated. Still more than 2<sup>32</sup> though.

Comment: @Joey: Randomly generated ones, sure - but I don't think there's anything stopping you from a 16-byte array into the `Guid` constructor with any values you want. Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @Joey: Well we're specifically talking about the .NET `Guid` type, and I still maintain that there are 2^128 possible values for that type.

Comment: @Joey: Sure, and you don't normally end up with strings that have values unassigned within Unicode - but they're still values which can easily be created.

Comment: What use is `GetHashCode` if two different instances can have the same value?  It can't be used reliably either to confirm that 2 things are the same, or that 2 things are different!

Comment: @Jez: It *can* be used to confirm that two things are different - if they have different hash codes, they can't be equal (assuming a proper implementation). If they have the same hash code, they *might* be equal. The point is that if you have a million keys in a map, and you're trying to find one of them, you can very rapidly narrow it down to "just the keys that have the right hash code" and then you can call Equals on all of those candidates to find out which key is actually the right one.

Answer (score 19):

Just today I've noticed another problem of the `Guid.GetHashCode()`: in Microsoft .NET implementation, not every "byte" of the `Guid` is hashed: there are 6 bytes of the `Guid` that aren't hashed, so any change to one of them won't ever change the hash code.

We can see it in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,925):

```
return _a ^ (((int)_b << 16) | (int)(ushort)_c) ^ (((int)_f << 24) | _k);
```

so the `_d`, `_e`, `_g`, `_h`, `_i`, `_j` bytes aren't hashed. This has an important impact with "sequential" `Guid`s, like:

```
c482fbe1-9f16-4ae9-a05c-383478ec9d13
c482fbe1-9f16-4ae9-a05c-383478ec9d14
c482fbe1-9f16-4ae9-a05c-383478ec9d15
...
c482fbe1-9f16-4ae9-a05c-383478ec9dff
c482fbe1-9f16-4ae9-a05c-383478ec9e00
c482fbe1-9f16-4ae9-a05c-383478ec9e01
```

with `Guid` like these, the number of different hashes generated is very small (256 different values), because the `3478ec9d`/`3478ec9e` won't be hashed.

Comment: Wow, very interesting observation.Not sure why MS wouldn't hash the whole GUID, but this is something to be aware of....

Comment: For version 1 UUID's the fields included in `GetHashCode()` are the 60 bit timestamp and parts of the MAC address. For version 4 UUID's (which you get from `Guid.NewGuid()`) almost all bytes of the GUID are random. So in these cases the algorithm seems OK.

Comment: I ran into this issue in production with GUIDs generated on an OracleDB. Can somebody explain why it does not hash all the values? Hard for me to believe that hashing additional 6 bytes would be a perf issue?

Comment: @PhilippAumayr Has been changed in .NET Core... Now all the bits are hased (see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Guid.cs#L795) The [commit](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/bcfdee0e362be74f1de318403aac4542e248c586) is from 2016:

Answer (score 13):

`GetHashCode()` returns an integer - it cannot be as unique as a `Guid`, so no - there might be collisions and uniqueness is not guaranteed.

The point of a hash code is that it should *distribute evenly across the hash range* so that collisions should be generally rare, you always have a chance of collision though and have to accommodate for that.

Comment: it should also be noted that GUIDs are not guaranteed to be unique

Comment: A duplicate GUID is rumored to be generated on December 21st, 2012.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry to disappoint you. The rumour was false.

Answer (score 5):

I was having exactly [the problem xanatos describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31587915/2998072) in another answer.  I have a class where two `Guid` values are used to distinguish different objects, and I found I was getting a horrible number of collisions (my Guids are not randomly generated).  Here is the code I used to solve the problem.  `Guid1` and `Guid2` are the properties of type `Guid` that distinguish the objects.  The code follows [the approach described by Jon Skeet here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/2998072).

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 173;
        foreach (Byte b in Guid1.ToByteArray().Concat(Guid2.ToByteArray()))
        {
            hash = hash * 983 + b;
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: This helped me.  I was looking for a simple "good enough" algorithm that could translate a GUID to an integer with low-ish likelihood of collisions.  The uniqueness of the value in my case doesn't need to be global -- it is unique in a very small context/dataset.  Good find here which I've validated with some unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

A Guid is a 128-bit number. An int is a 32-bit number, so it can't be "as unique" as the Guid.

Besides, GetHashCode returns ... a hash code, it's not meant to be unique in any way. See other discussions here on SO about why GetHashCode() exists.