# Can't output Guid Hashcode

Tags: sql, vb.net, guid, hashcode

I'm trying to use the hashcode of a guid as a random voucher name for a website, and have been trying to write new records to a SQL table with the Hashcode variable but it doesn't work.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@voucherName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters("@voucherName").Value = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()
```

When using that code it just puts a whole Guid in the field. How can I make sure it's only going to use a hashcode instead?

**Edit**

This is the full function used to add the record to my database. It is passed a guid from another function to act as `strID`

```
Dim connect As New SqlConnection
    Dim query As String = ""
    connect.ConnectionString = "SERVER = SERVER-SQL01; Trusted_Connection = yes; DATABASE = GlobalPCSQL"
    connect.Open()
    query = "INSERT into dbo.X_WW_VOUCHER_DETAILS (vID, voucherName, expiryDate, validUses, cartOrItem, validStockCode, discountAmount, dollarOrPercent, freebieStockCode, chkCartTotal, cartTotalOverUnder, cartTotalAmount, chkItemPrice, itemPriceOverUnder, itemPriceAmount, chkNoInCart, noInCartOverUnder, noInCartAmount, chkNoOfProduct, noOfProductOverUnder, noOfProductAmount, chkRequiredStockCode, requiredStockCode, category, description) "
    query += "VALUES(@vID, @voucherName, @expiryDate, 1, 0, , 10, 1, , 1, 0, 200, 0,  ,  , 0, , , 0, , , 0, , , Welcome Voucher, 10% off first order over $200. Valid 7 days.)"

    Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connect)
    command.Parameters.Add("@vID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
    command.Parameters("@vID").Value = strID
    command.Parameters.Add("@voucherName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters("@voucherName").Value = Guid.NewGuid.ToString().GetHashCode()
    command.Parameters.Add("@expiryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    Dim exDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    exDate.AddDays(7)
    command.Parameters("@expiryDate").Value = exDate

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connect.Close()
```

What's really weird is that whether I use `guid.newguid().toString()` or `strID.toString()` to start things off... both vID and voucherName end up with the same guid as their value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, are you looking for a hashcode like this?

> "OZVV5TpP4U6wJthaCORZEQ"

Then this answer might be useful:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
string GuidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
GuidString = GuidString.Replace("=","");
GuidString = GuidString.Replace("+","");
```

Extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730268/unique-random-string-generation).
On the linked post there are many other useful answers. Please take a look!

Other useful links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx
- [What is hashCode used for? Is it unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-use-for-is-it-unique)
- [Guid & GetHashCode uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326593/guid-gethashcode-uniqueness)

**Edit:**
Doublechecking your code, you might change it from `Guid.NewGuid.ToString().GetHashCode()`

to

`Guid.NewGuid.GetHashCode().ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried it out but for some reason it's still sticking the same guid in both fields. I've changed "@voucherName" to reference the new GuidString variable but it just slaps the same strID (guid) in as the vID field.

Comment: @ChrisHinton I would advise you to debug and step through.
Check your hashcode during runtime and see if it's working.
You might change your code from  Guid.NewGuid.ToString().GetHashCode() to Guid.NewGuid.GetHashCode().ToString().

Comment: You ever realise you've been doing something really stupid and don't want to admit how dense you've been... I managed to forget that my site couldn't reference that function properly (something weird about session state, this site is a mess)... so I copied it into a different page... which was referencing strID.ToString(). Genius.