# Select unique members using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Clubs that has a list of Member property in it. How do I get a List of unique members?

Here's why this question is different than what you're suggesting as duplicate:
This is a bit different than the example in that one of the properties of my class is another class -- not a simple int or string.

My class looks like this:

```
public class Club
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ClubName { get; set; }
   public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

And the member class looks like this:

```
public class Member
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }
}
```

To illustrate the point a bit more...

```
var myClubs = new List<Club>();
myClubs = getSomeData();

var uniqueMembers = myClubs.Select()...
```

Comment: If the ID is the same, then it's the same member. I want to get the unique members from a List<Clubs> and a member can be in multiple clubs which is why I just want to get a list of List<Member> that are unique in List<Club>

Comment: @Sam There are *plenty* of examples and solutions to this. Please do a bit of research. Searching for `C# unique list` is enough to get you a bunch of examples.

Comment: @Rob You mean I shouldn't have asked?

Comment: I think you are looking for distinct: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Sam I mean you should have searched for an existing solution before asking this question. Otherwise, SO (and the internet in general, really) will end up polluted with problems which have been solved many times in the past, making it hard for interesting and new problems to be seen and answered. Having 100 answers saying "Use `Distinct`" isn't really that useful. A good rule of thumb, I've found, is to not ask a question before doing at least 30 minutes of research first. If you come up short after that time, you've probably got a new and interesting question on your hands.

Comment: @Drew - This isn't a duplicate. The link you gave was for producing a distinct list of strings, this is for a class. The answer here is more complex.

Comment: @Enigmativity The linked question has the solution to this question as well. In particular atik sarker's answer and Dan Busha's answer. It very much is a duplicate.

Comment: Retracted, thanks. Someone consider hammering it if need be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255121/get-a-list-of-distinct-values-in-list

Comment: @Sam: so what is the final output that you want? A list of distinct members (`IEnumerable<Member>`)? Or a list of list of members (`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Member>`)?

Comment: @code4life I'm trying to a get a List<Member> that contains unique members across multiple clubs i.e. not just unique members within one club but in myClubs = new List<Club>

Comment: @Drew - Don't delete comments like that. It make it hard to understand the conversation.

Comment: I placed the url in the retracted line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var result = myClubs
    .SelectMany(x => x.Members)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

Based on the comments, members are equal if they have the same `Id`.

So, first you use `SelectMany` to select all members from all clubs, then you group them by the `Id`.

Now each group will just contain multiple instances of the same member (or just a single member if there are no duplicates of such member).

Then you would just select the first member of each group to get the unique members.

Comment: Yeah, this is the classic way to do it if you don't want to implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: Any comment for the down vote?

Comment: Someone doesn't like our approach. I wonder why?

Comment: Hmm... I dunno why anyone would do that. Don't worry, I +1'd ya  :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
List<Member> distinctMembers =
    myClubs
        .SelectMany(c => c.Members)
        .GroupBy(m => m.Id)
        .SelectMany(m => m.Take(1))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? This works precisely as asked for and is quite clean.

Comment: This answer is semantically the same (`Take(1).SelectMany(m => m)` vs `Select(m => m.First())` as [a solution found in the proposed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24360130/563532) you said was *not* a duplicate, and subsequently had the vote retracted. This question has been asked *so many times before* on stack overflow, and I'm really surprised the attention it's gotten and responses from high-rep users without anyone closing as dupe (and actively contesting it).

Comment: @Rob, I re-looked at it. You're right. It was a dup.

Comment: Might be better to just remove this answer... plus the double flattening projections (`SelectMany`) - I am not a fan of.

Comment: @code4life - I kind of like the `.Take(1).SelectMany(m => m)` instead of the `.Select(m => m.First())` as it avoids blocking operations. I know in this case, with the `GroupBy`, that there must be at least one element, but I like to maintain the habit of not using blocking operations.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yeah, but double flattening? That's a practice that could potentially be quite expensive. Think of all the list of lists being traversed...

Comment: @code4life - It's no more that calling `.First()`. Remember that LINQ is deferred so `.Take(1).SelectMany(m => m)` is only one hit on the source, as is `.First()`.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that `GroupBy(..).Take(1).SelectMany(m=>m)` returns the duplicate members of the first group while `GroupBy(...).Select(g => g.First())` returns the first member of every group.

Comment: @IvanStoev - You are spot on. I made a stupid mistake. I've fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Override GetHashCode and Equals methods.

```
public class Member
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // if each member has a unique Id assigned to him/her
        // you can simply return Id
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var member = (Member)obj;
        return member == null
            ? false
            : Id == member.Id;
    }
}
```

Then to get a list of unique members for each club, you can call:

```
var uniqueMembersForEachClub = myClubs.Select(c => c.Members.Distinct());
```

And to get a list of unique members for all clubs, you can call:

```
var uniqueMembers = myClubs.SelectMany(c => c.Members).Distinct();
```

You will need to include:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Good luck!

Comment: But is equality strictly based on member id only? What if we want to allow editing and member id is also an editable field (I mean, it does have a `set`, right....)? We're kind of using a sledgehammer approach here. Really, the targeted approach would be to use `IEqualityComparer`, because distinctness can be relative.

Comment: It is bad to base `GetHashCode` on properties that can change value. If it were `public Guid Id { get; private set; }` it would be a much better choice, but as it stands external code can modify the `Id` and that breaks the hash code.

Comment: Nice comment by Jon Skeet on using `Guid.GetHashCode` and why that would be nonsensical.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326593/guid-gethashcode-uniqueness

Comment: @code4life - Are you replying to my comment?

Comment: Making Id private set would be great. However, my answer was to show how to use GetHashCode and Equals methods. You don't have to implement GetHashCode the way I do (Thanks to Jon Skeet's answer, I do realize now that Guid.GetHashCode is not always unique). However, by implementing GetHashCode and Equals methods properly, you shift all the logics to the model, and make your life easier when you want to get a list of unique members (or whatever you want to do with the objects of the class).