# Two different random number generators giving the same answer?

Tags: c#, random

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //random number gen
        Console.WriteLine("Array Random Number:");
        randomGenA();
        Console.WriteLine("------------------");

        //LIST: random movie picker...
        Console.WriteLine("List Random Number:");
        randomGenB();
        Console.WriteLine("------------------");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void randomGenA()
    {
        Random randomA = new Random();
        int randomNumA = randomA.Next(51);

        Console.WriteLine(randomNumA);

    }
    static void randomGenB()
    {
        Random randomB = new Random();
        int randomNumB = randomB.Next(0,51);

        Console.WriteLine(randomNum);
    }
 }
```

I wanted them both to produce two different random numbers but instead I keep getting the same random number from both of them. Why does it do this?

Comment: The time difference between the instantiations of these two `Random` objects is minimal, causing them to have the same seed. Introduce a delay (please don't) or share the `Random` instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060961/seeding-a-pseudo-random-number-generator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thanks for the explanation!

Comment: add System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); between your method call

Comment: create one `Random randomB = new Random();` in class and use it in both methods.

Comment: Many good solutions here, the one I have not seen yet: use a random number from first generator as seed for second. Easiest one though is probably the shared instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a class level random and use it in your methods:

```
private static Random _random = new Random();
```

Your methods would look like:

```
static void randomGenA()
{
    int randomNumA = _random.Next(51);

    Console.WriteLine(randomNumA);

}
static void randomGenB()
{
    int randomNumB = _random.Next(0,51);

    Console.WriteLine(randomNum);
}
```

Check this out for further reading: http://www.dotnetperls.com/random

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Two `Random`s with the same seed will provide the same sequence of numbers.  Simply don't use the same seed.  If you don't specify a seed, it uses the system time.  Wait some time between the two instantiations and it will use two different system times.