# C# - Why does it set to magenta every time?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set the console background color to a random color but it always returns magenta. What would I have to change to fix this issue. Thanks!

```
    using System;

    namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomInt = random.Next(0, 6);
            while(randomInt < 7) 
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                randomInt++;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                randomInt++;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                randomInt++;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                randomInt++;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                randomInt++;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                randomInt++;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                randomInt++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger and step thru - you should see your mistake...

Comment: I don't understand the question - the last color that gets set by the `while` loop is magenta. You probably want to use a different construct, such as `if` or `switch` `case`

Comment: Apparently you wanted to create some sort of a [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) in hope that `randomInt` is reevaluated for being `< 7` after each instruction within the `while`, and that it will automatically exit the `while` when it happens. That's not how it works.

Comment: You could try seeding your random number so that it doesn't always start out with the same sequence. See this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060961/seeding-a-pseudo-random-number-generator-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also, in your while loop, you're not giving it time to see the color change. So it goes all the way to the end and you end up with the same color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood the concept of a loop I believe and it may not be the tool for you to use.
To randomize colors, you would have to associate them with a number and then pick a number and select the associated color.

The ConsoleColor is an enumeration which means each value is already associated with a number. You can select a random value from the enumeration using the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132126/how-do-i-select-a-random-value-from-an-enumeration).

If you want to specifically only have a few colors from the enumeration, you will have to create your own array of the values you want and select a value from that array.

Here is an example of how to select a random item from an array.

```
Random random = new Random();
ConsoleColor[] colors = new ConsoleColor[] { ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Blue };
var myRandomColor = colors[random.Next(0, colors.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually setting all colors and last magenta. I think you should use if or case statement if you want to set colors conditionally. If you comment the magenta assignmnent you will always get yellow background

```
        while(randomInt < 7) 
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            randomInt++;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            randomInt++;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            randomInt++;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            randomInt++;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            randomInt++;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            randomInt++;
            //Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            //randomInt++; //THIS WILL ALWAYS BE YELLOW
        }
```

I think that what you need is a case statement:

```
switch(randomInt)
{
     case 0:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        break;
     case 1:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        break;
     ///....AND SO ON
}
```